# Scrollable menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am coding with React and I am trying to make a horizontal scrollable menu at the top of my application. When I have scrolled and selected a tab, I want this to be animated such that it floats nicely to the middle of the visible menu. The current selected menu tab can be outside of the view (e.g. if I have scrolled horizontally far away from it).

So when I click Tab no. 4:

[image]

I want this to happen (that Tab no. 4 are smooth sliding to the center of the menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use some great plugins like [this](http://react-component.github.io/tabs/examples/swipeInkTabBar.html) in order to achieve desired functionality